# Attach new disk to Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have installed mysql in a A4 Linux VM in Azure and I'm running out of disk space. I saw that the primary disk space is 29GB only and the temporary disk space is 600GB, but I don't want to store mysql's data to the temporary disk because of the possibility of losing them.

I want to attach a new disk to my VM and I have two questions:

1) What type of storage is the best for my case?
2) If I attach a disk, will mysql data be distributed to this disk automatically when the primary disk space runs out or should I make further adjustments (i.e. change mysql's data_dir or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a new data disk to your VM.  The steps are described here in the Azure documentation: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-tutorial/#attachdisk

No, the newly attached disk won't expand the existing one.

Comment: ok thanks! So I have to change the whole data_dir at the newly added disk right? :/